# Block/Remove/Ignore a specific cookie

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-addons

I'm using a Chrome add-in to scrape some websites. One of these sites is kucoin.com.

In the P2P trading part, the site uses a header filter in which you can select your currency. However, once you've landed on a page, it installs a cookie which remembers what currency you were previously using. For me this is very annoying because my scraper programming uses direct URL's to scrape the currencies I'm interested in.

I'll clarify using an example:

1. If you visit https://www.kucoin.com/nl/otc/buy/BTC-EUR for the first time: you land on the EURO currency listings.
2. The scraper proceeds to scrape and paginate. I've also programmed it to use the currency filter to scrape all currencies available. For the sake simplifying my example let's say the last page it visits is filtered on USD. The current URL here is https://www.kucoin.com/nl/otc/buy/BTC-USD
3. The scraper should start its new cycle on for example Ethereum (ETH). The start page should be https://www.kucoin.com/nl/otc/buy/ETH-EUR
4. Yet, the scraper will now start on https://www.kucoin.com/nl/otc/buy/ETH-USD , not ETH-EUR, because its last page visited was USD, and it gives preference to the cookie when loading a page.

So I'm looking for a way to either:

- Block a **specific** cookie from being created or read
- Have Chrome ignore existing cookies when loading a page
- Clear the specific (or all, at this point I don't care anymore) cookie once every second, while the scraper is running.

I've tried all cookie blocker add-in's I could find. They usually don't do anything because they're not blocking **first**-party cookies, or they block all cookies or "on-device site data"; which keeps the page from loading all together.

EditThisCookie (https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg) seemed to be the most promising to doing what I'm looking for, but for some reason it's not detecting or blocking the cookie I'm looking for. Probably it only looks at second- or third-party cookies.

To prove that the cookie is the issue, I've been using the single-click Cookie Remover (https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/cookie-remover/kcgpggonjhmeaejebeoeomdlohicfhce), which once clicked very nicely says it has removed one cookie, and then entering a direct URL works **once**. Because after this page load, the cookie is created once again. Obviously I can't be manually clicking this button once every second either.

Please help me find a solution to this problem which has been driving me crazy for days!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can go to this settings link in Chrome to delete the cookies for a specific site ([www.kucoin.com](http://www.kucoin.com) here) and click **Delete data**, but this is the same as your cookie remover extension. It would need to be added into the steps for your scraper:

```
chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.kucoin.com
```

Or manually: Chrome > Settings > Privacy and security > Third-party cookies >
See all site data and permissions > search for site URL > Delete content

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?hl=en-GB#zippy=%2Cdelete-cookies-from-a-site

Opening a new incognito window works as well

---

Chrome used to have a setting in `chrome://settings/cookies` for a list of "Sites that can never use cookies", but that seems to be removed in my version along with other ways to block first-party cookies (unless I'm missing them). Edge has a block list under `edge://settings/content/cookies` for example.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Your suggestion is for deleting it manually. My scraper tool loads a new page every second, so I can't be deleting manually every second for hours. I'd really need to find a way to do it automatically.

You did however help me with your incognito suggestion. I had given it a try but then found my scraper doesn't work with incognito mode. But looking deeper I have found a way to get it running. 

Thank you!